# Dynamic lambda expression - compare properties in a List<T> postion 0 with properties in position 1

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I'm looking for some help to dynamically create a lambda expression.

Below is a sample of my classes.  I want to be able to pass in a string that will be the property I want to compare on.

I have simplified my model down for the purpose of this post.  Original model has over 300 columns (not my design) and is added to on a regular bases.

The List will have only 2 records in it.  I would like to compare the property in List[0].Property != List[1].Property.

```
public class DataRecord
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public IList<Record> Records { set; get; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string Name {set; get;}
    public string Address {set; get;}
    public string Postcode {set; get;}
}
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
DataRecord
        {
            Id = "ID",                
            Records = new List<Record>
            {
                new Record {Name = "name1", Address = "someAddress1", Postcode = "postcode1"},
                new Record {Name = "name2", Address = "someAddress2", Postcode = "postcode2"}
            }

        };
```

I would like to say return the record if the first address is different from the second address or first name is different from second name etc.

I'm wanting to dynamically create this:

```
ListOfDataRecords.Where(dataRecord => dataRecord.Records[0].Property != dataRecord.Records[1].Property)
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
    private static Expression<Func<DataRecord, bool>> CreateFilterExpression(string propertyName)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRecord), "dataRecord");

        var member = Expression.Property(parameter, "Records");
        var member2 = Expression.Property(parameter, "Records");


        var arType = Array.CreateInstance(member.Type.GetGenericArguments().Single(), 0).GetType();
        var arType2 = Array.CreateInstance(member2.Type.GetGenericArguments().Single(), 0).GetType();


        var indexedProperty1 = Expression.ArrayIndex(member, Expression.Constant(0));
        var indexedProperty2 = Expression.ArrayIndex(member2, Expression.Constant(1));

        var body = Expression.Equal(member, member2);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<DataRecord, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }
```

This doesn't work and this is the error I am getting:

```
Argument must be array (Parameter 'array')
```

Can anyone help me work out how to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be not to use reflection and fiddle with expressions, but create extension methods, so you can use it as if they were LINQ methods.
See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

### Using Lambda expressions

Convert the property name to a property selector, and call the filter method using the property selector:

```
static IQueryable<DataRecord> FilterByName(
    this IQueryable<DataRecord> dataRecords,
    string propertyName)
{
    // TODO: what if propertyName null or invalid?

    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case nameof(Record.Address):
            return dataRecords.FilterByProperty(record => record.Address);
        case nameof(Record.Postcode):
            return dataRecords.FilterByProperty(record => record.Postcode);
        case nameof(Record.Name):
            return dataRecords.FilteryByProperty(record => record.Name);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(propertyName));
    }
```

The filter method using a property selector:

```
static IQueryable<DataRecord> FilterByProperty<TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<DataRecord> dataRecords,
    Expression<Func<Record, TProperty>> propertySelector)
{
    // TODO: handle null dataRecords, null propertySelector

    return dataRecords.Where(dataRecord => !propertySelector(dataRecord.Records[0])
                                    .Equals(propertySelector(dataRecord.Records[1]);
```

Usage:

```
string propertyName = ...
IQueryable<DataRecord> originalDataRecords = ...
IQueryable<DataRecord> filteredDataRecords = originalDataRecords.FilterByProperty(propertyName);
```

### If you really want to use Expressions

Split your problem into subproblems:

- Convert the string to a PropertySelector:
- Using a propertySelector, return an `Expression<Func<DataRecord, bool>>`

String to PropertySelector: as an extension method:

```
static Expression<Func<Record, string>> ToPropertySelector(this string propertyName)
{
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case nameof(Record.Address):
            return (record) => record.Address;
        case nameof(Record.Postcode):
            return (record) => record.Postcode;
        case nameof(Record.Name):
            return (record) => record.Name;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(propertyName));
    }
}
```

PropertySelector to FilterExpression:

```
static Expression<Func<DataRecord, bool>> ToFilterExpression(
    Func<Record, string> propertySelector)
{
    return (dataRecord) => !propertySelector(dataRecord.Records[0])
                    .Equals(propertySelector(dataRecord.Records[1]));
}
```

Usage:

```
string propertyName = ...
Expression<Func<DataRecord, bool>> filterExpression = propertyName
    .ToPropertySelector()
    .ToFilterExpression();

var validDataRecords = dbContext.DataRecords.Where(filterExpression);
```

If you will be using this several times, consider to put this also in an extension method

Comment: Thank you Harald.

I do understand your ecellent suggestion to make own extension method for handling this however I did simplify my data models here for posting my question. (Should have said this in the post).

The model (not my design) has over 300 properties and it's the case that that can be added to on a regular bases.  I need something less strict on the properties and I wouldn't like them all hardcoded in a case statement.

Comment: David: how many times per month will you be adding a new property? How much time does it cost to add one "case" to the switch? How much time will it cost to debug the error if someone types an incorrect property string? The separate method to translate the string to the lambda makes it easier to find the error, since it is on one place. It is almost always only meaningful to use strings to refer to property names if the source of the string is external: operator input, or file. Check correctness and translate at the input and you don't have to check again.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it looks like your expression is generating `dataRecord.Record[0] == dataRecord.Record[1]`. I think "Record" is a typo and should be "Records".

**Edit**

After re-reading the exception message, i realized the problem is that the array index operator *only* works for arrays. What you are trying to access is not an array, but a class with an indexer defined. The indexer is actually exposed as a  a get and set method on the class, which can be invoked via `Expression.Call`.

```
private static Expression<Func<DataRecord, bool>> CreateFilterExpression(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRecord), "dataRecord");
    var records = Expression.Property(parameter, "Records");
    var indexer = typeof(IList<Record>).GetMethod("get_Item");
    var record0 = Expression.Call(records, indexer, Expression.Constant(0));
    var record1 = Expression.Call(records, indexer, Expression.Constant(1));
    var property0 = Expression.Property(record0, propertyName);
    var property1 = Expression.Property(record1, propertyName);
    var body = Expression.NotEqual(property0, property1);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<DataRecord, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Comment: It seems that OP wants `body = Expression.NotEqual(...`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, yes it's a typo, was trying to simplify my models for the post and that was a typo.  Sadly the code you have post is just the same as what I've already tried and have the same error: Argument must be array (Parameter 'array').

Comment: Ah, I just clicked - you're accessing a list, not an array